# How to place a variable containing an array of strings into Regex c#

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, wpf

I'm new to using regex and searching texts.
I want to have multiple words being searched at the same time in a text and I was thinking about doing the following

```
string text = new TextRange(rtfMain.Document.ContentStart, rtfMain.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

        string[] searchWords = { "Danny", "Lucy", "Marco" };
        Regex rx = new Regex( searchWords,
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            ResultList.Add(match.ToString());
        }
```

but regex doesn't seem to accept the variable of

```
string[] searchWords
```

How can I make it work, or is my approach wrong in achieving what I need?

Comment: In python, I would replace the `searchWords` with `'|'.join(searchWords)`

Comment: On a side note, why are you using the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option?  If your answer is "because someone told me it makes the regex run faster," you need a better reason.  Using that option incurs a significant amount of overhead, and in most cases the benefit is nowhere near enough to offset that cost. ([ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/12/256783.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the search words into one string, each separated by `|`.

```
string searchWords = "Danny|Lucy|Marco";
Regex rx = new Regex( searchWords,
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you need the array, join the strings dynamically.

```
string[] searchWordsArray = { "Danny", "Lucy", "Marco" };

string searchWords = String.Join("|", searchWordsArray)
Regex rx = new Regex( searchWords,
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match for `Danny` or `Lucy` or `Marco` you can just put a pipe (|) between the terms, as the `Regex` constructor only accepts a single string as a pattern.

To make a single (pipe-separated) string from your array, you can just do:

```
string[] searchWords = { "Danny", "Lucy", "Marco" };
string pattern = string.Join("|", searchWords);
Regex rx = new Regex( pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```